# Permutations and Combinations htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any way to use permutations in htaccess for RewriteRule ?
For example I have this url:

```
http://localmachine/index.php?c=category&brand=mybrand&country=mycountry&offer=yes&new=yes
```

The rewrite url should look like:

```
   http://localmachine/category/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes
```

But I want to use brand, country, offer and new in any position on the url.
In the url I could have 2, 3 or all of them in any position.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/brand-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&brand=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/gramaj-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&gramaj=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/oferta-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&oferta=da [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/nou-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&nou=da [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/brand-([^/]+)/gramaj-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&brand=$2&gramaj=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/brand-([^/]+)/nou-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&brand=$2&nou=da [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/brand-([^/]+)/oferta-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&brand=$2&oferta=da [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/gramaj-([^/]+)/nou-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&gramaj=$2&nou=da [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/gramaj-([^/]+)/oferta-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&gramaj=$2&oferta=da [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/gramaj-([^/]+)/brand-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&gramaj=$2&brand=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/oferta-da/nou-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&oferta=da&nou=da [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/oferta-da/gramaj-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&oferta=da&gramaj=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/oferta-da/brand-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&oferta=da&brand=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/nou-da/gramaj-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&nou=da&gramaj=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/nou-da/brand-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&nou=da&brand=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/nou-da/oferta-da/?$ index.php?c=$1&nou=da&oferta=da [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Is `/category/` always at the start?

Comment: Category always at the beginning

Comment: Is for a filtering system

Comment: Tip: don't fiddle with `.htaccess`. Redirect `.*` to `index.php` and do the parsing in php, much more conveniently.

Comment: can you please explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursion based rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite /category to /index.php?c=category
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/?c=$1 [L,QSA]

# rewrite /category/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes
# to /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+.+)/?$ /index.php/$2?c=$1 [L,QSA]

# rewrite /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
# converts any /name-val/ to query parameter name=val in every rewrite
# stopping when there is no part left after /index.php
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite:

```
/category/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes
```

to this:

```
/index.php?new=yes&offer=yes&country=mycountry&brand=mybrand&c=category
```

**PS:** I strongly suggest you to test this code independently first and then add your rules **below these 2 rules**.

Comment: Yes no issues with double quotes here. You can remove them if you don't want since there is space in rule pattern.

Comment: can you explain please ? every rule

Comment: I can add explanation in the answer but but did it work for you?

Comment: Yes is working, but not for the category as start point ex: http://local/category is working with http://local/category/brand-mybrand

Comment: Added explanation and `www.localhost/category/brand-mybrand` worked for me.

Comment: Yes but www.localhost/category/  just the category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60025/discussion-between-speedy-and-anubhava).